# Scala - reducing a map based on changed key

Tags: scala, dictionary

Lets say have the following Map data

```
val testMap: Map[String, Int] = Map("AAA_abc" -> 1,
                                    "AAA_anghesh" -> 2,
                                    "BBB_wfejw" -> 3,
                                    "BBB_qgqwe" -> 4,
                                    "C_fkee" -> 5)
```

Now I want to reduce the map by `key.split("_").head` and add all the values for the keys that became equal. So for this example the `Map` should result into:

```
Map(AAA -> 3, BBB -> 7, C -> 5)
```

What would be the correct way to do so in Scala?
I tried constructions with `groupBy` and `reduceLeft` but could not find a solution.

Comment: can u show what code have u tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
testMap.groupBy(_._1.split("_").head).mapValues(_.values.sum)
```

Comment: You could use `mapValues(_.values.sum)` instead

Comment: I see `groupBy(...).mapValues(...)` a lot. I don't know why there isn't an `aggregateBy` or `reduceBy` in the standard library...@Chirlo's anser is pretty much implementing that...

Answer (score 1):

A variation in one pass:

```
testMap.foldLeft(Map[String,Int]())( (map, kv) => {
  val key = kv._1.split("_").head
  val previous = map.getOrElse(key,0)
  map.updated(key, previous + kv._2) })
```